# What happens to up-votes if an account gets deleted?

Tags: discussion, voting, technical

If a user were to up-vote a question or answer of mine, and then their account gets deleted, does this change my total amount of up-votes?

Or does Stack Overflow only store the amount of up-votes allotted to a user, regardless of its origin?

It is a pretty technical question, I'm just curious about how the back-end stores up-votes?

Are there any other reasons why the up-votes allotted to me might change?

Comment: reputation is calculated. http://stackoverflow.com/reputation if an upvote is removed, your rep will be recalculated without said upvote, rather than the reputation being removed from a total.

Comment: You'll loose it! How bad is that! You put your efforts in giving a great answer, were rewarded for it... and then loose your reward.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By default, when a user is deleted, their upvotes and downvotes are reversed.

This is why moderators are very hesitant to delete well established users that have a long voting history, and tend to favor other alternatives (such as long suspensions, anonymization of content, etc.).

> Or does Stackoverflow only store the amount of up-votes allotted to a user, regardless of its origin?

They couldn't do this.  If they did, then you could vote on anything as many times as you wanted, rather than just once.  They *need* to keep track of who has voted for what, and when.  (They *also* compute the totals for posts, as an optimization, but they can't *just* keep track of that.)

Comment: OK, makes sense that they would track the origin of an up-vote, but still I did not think that a user's up-vote would be reversed...but I guess it would make sense to have the ability to reverse it to prevent abuse or what not

Comment: Here is a relevant [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/330457).

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading, since when high-rep users *are* deleted, it's customary to preserve their votes in most cases.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: yes, you''re right. I looked this up, and then deleted my comment. Thanks.

Comment: "If they did, then you could vote on anything as many times as you wanted" nah; sounds like `FOREIGN KEY ... ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: @Joshua What are you talking about?  That statement is merely explaining why votes need to be tied to a user for at least as long as the user exists.